# How to create username and password with creation of database in phpmyadmin using PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created database multiple and running `SQL` script in `PHP` code, but don't know how to create individual username and password of each database.

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user and database by the name of `matin11` with this code. you can change user name.

```
CREATE USER 'matin11'@'localhost';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'matin11'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `matin11`;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `matin11`.* TO 'matin11'@'localhost';
```

Comment: you can use it with PHP.

Comment: So my hostname will bee my server name like 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `matin11`.* TO 'matin11'@'168.192.1.1:338;  and last question how i can check is working in localhost

Comment: you must check it with php. like this query. `$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: You must learn how to use mysql query in php. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `matin11`.* TO 'matin11'@'localhost'; is not working in the server of GoDaddy

Comment: You must post any code. or error to find your problem. how can know what is the error.

Comment: @DhawalBhatt if my answer was helpful. vote up me and mark it as green,thanks

Answer (score -1):

On the phpMyAdmin default page (localhost) click on the "Privileges" link
1. Click on the "Add a new User link"
2. Assign the User a login and password
3. Where it says "Database for User" select "None"
4. Leave all checkboxes in global privileges unchecked

Press the "Go" button
You should see the new user in the User overview. Global privileges should say "Usage".

1. Click on the edit icon next the the User's account
2. Under "Database-specific privileges" where it says "Add privileges on the following
3. database" chose the database(s) you wish to assign to the user
4. Assign the User whatever privileges you wish them to have for that database
5. Press the "Go" button

Comment: I required code not manual function